Is the group of 4 by 4 nilpotent triangular matrices a semidirect product?
Let $N$ be the Lie group of 4 by 4 nilpotent triangular matrices with 1 on the diagonal. Let us denote by $E_{ij}$ the square matrix with entry 1 where the $i$th row and $j$th column meet, all the other entries being zero. Then the Lie algebra is given by
$\{ E_{12},E_{34}, E_{13},E_{14},E_{23}, E_{24}\}.$
$N$ has a normal abelian subgroup $A$, whose Lie algebra is given by  given by
$\{ E_{13},E_{14},E_{23}, E_{24}\}.$ In addition $N$ has a abelian subgroup H, whose Lie algebra is $\{ E_{12},E_{34}\}.$
Is $N$ a semidirect product $N = A \rtimes H$? or is just a extension of $A$ by $H$?

So, you want to treat them as a Lie group additively? That is, homeomorphic to $(\mathbb R^6,+)?$ They aren't a Lie group under multiplication, because they don't have inverses.

They are a Lie group under multiplication, if you consider the exponential map of them  elements in the Lie algebra, they have an inverse since they have 1 in each entries of the diagonal.

That doesn't mean they form a Lie group, they form a Lie algebra. If you want the exponential images of these matrices, mention that.

The upper triangular matrices with 1  in each entries of the diagonal is a Lie group, they are close under the multiplication. It is a nilpotent Lie group. The case of 3 by 3 matrices is well known as the Heisenberg group. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group

defining the Lie algebra is an equivalent way to define the group

Sure, but calling a Lie algebra a Lie group is misleading.

Yes, you basically said everything, except that there is a "retract", i.e., an homomorphism $\pi\colon N\to H$ such that $\pi(h)=h$ for $h\in H$. In terms of short exact sequences, we have
$$ 1 \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow N \overset\pi\longrightarrow \mathbb R^2 \longrightarrow 1 $$
with
$$ \pi\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\ & 1 & a_{23} & a_{24} \\ & & 1 & a_{34} \\ & & & 1 \end{pmatrix} = (a_{12}, a_{34}). $$
Moreover this sequence splits, using the obvious section $\sigma\colon\mathbb R^2\to H\le N$ (the only thing to check is that the $H$ you hightlighted is indeed an abelian subgroup), so we have a semi-direct product.

Thank you very much for you kind answer. Could you please explain me why we need to check H is abelian?

The emphasis should be both on "abelian" and "subgroup". We need to check that $$\sigma(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & x & 0 & 0 \ & 1 & 0 & 0 \ & & 1 & y \ & & & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ is a morphism. (We also need to check that $\pi$ is a morphism. For $\pi$, it seemed immediate to me. Now that I write this (block) matrix, the fact that $\sigma$ is a morphism is also immediate to me.)
